# Date and Month Mixup in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

In Pandas, I am trying to format a date column from String to proper date so that I can export it to ElasticSearch. However, date and month are getting mixed up. I have given an example below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['12/03/2020 0:00', '11/02/2019 0:00', '10/01/2020 0:00'], 
                'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre'], 
                'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000]})
```

Date is entered in dd/mm/YYYY format.

```
df['Date1'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year  
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date1']).month
df['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date1']).day
df
```

This results in the following data frame where the date and month are interchanged.Year is extracted correct.

```
          Date      Event   Cost    Date1       Year    Month   Day
0   12/03/2020 0:00 Music   10000   2020-12-03  2020    12  3
1   11/02/2019 0:00 Poetry  5000    2019-11-02  2019    11  2
2   10/01/2020 0:00 Theatre 15000   2020-10-01  2020    10  1
```

Can someone provide inputs on how to format the date column in an appropriate way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert the data to real datetimes first:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Happily, the default parameters seem to work for parsing your example data:

```
>>> df
        Date    Event   Cost
0 2020-12-03    Music  10000
1 2019-11-02   Poetry   5000
2 2020-10-01  Theatre  15000
```

If you need the separate d/m/y columns, you can access the series' `dt` property instead of converting via a DatetimeIndex:

```
>>> df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
>>> # ... etc ...
>>> df
        Date    Event   Cost  Year
0 2020-12-03    Music  10000  2020
1 2019-11-02   Poetry   5000  2019
2 2020-10-01  Theatre  15000  2020
```

Comment: When write to a CSV file post df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), the date and months are getting interchanged.

Comment: @Ravi What do you mean? If you're seeing e.g. `2020-12-03` in your CSV, everything is just as it should be, and you're seeing ISO 8601 dates (see e.g. https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: If for some terrible reason you do not want to use ISO 8601 dates, `to_csv` does accept `date_format`, but just please don't.